# Requirements to access IP Camera using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera, ip, requirements

I'm new to IP cameras and I know there are quite a lot of topics about this in the forum already, but I can't find a concrete answer for my needs.

I want to access an IP camera using OpenCV in Python from a Windows PC. As I don't have a camera yet, I need to buy one and I can't figure out, what requirements this camera needs to have.

For example, there are quite cheap IP cameras (e.g. Xi****) which say they come with an Android or iOS app and are only accessible via those.

I thought you can access any IP cam via OpenCV, but now I'm not sure anymore... can anyone give me an overview, what specs an IP cam needs, to be accessed via OpenCV on Windows? I don't want to buy a camera and later realize, that I can't access the video stream.

I'm really sorry, if this has already been asked, but I can't find a satisfying answer to this question and Google doesn't seem to be very helpful...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check for IP cam that can transmit RTSP opencv know how to work with this type of stream.

Comment: That's it? So all cams with RTSP can be accessed via OpenCV? And are there other protocolls? I really can't find an overview about this...

Comment: Edit: I'm asking, because I read, that HTTP is working as well. But nothing about other protocolls and there doesn't seem to be anything in the OpenCV documentation

Comment: see VideoCapture() [2/3] in  https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html  have what can you pass to opencv

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. The thing is: I've asked some manufacturers and they said, even though their cameras stream RTSP and you can access it via vlc-player, it is not possible to access it via OpenCV, but didn't tell me why. Is it, because the stream got the wrong codec? I'm sorry, but I am pretty new to this topic...